# Will finished() signal of QFutureWatcher be fired if job completes before it is attached?

Tags: c++, qt5, qfuture, qfuturewatcher

Will the `finished()` signal of `QFutureWatcher` always be fired, even if the concurrent job that the `QFuture` represents has completed before the `QFutureWatcher` is attached to the `QFuture`?

Consider the following example:

```
// Start some computation.
QFuture<int> future = QtConcurrent::run(...);

// [A] At this point some time may pass where the computation might finish concurrently

// Instaciate watcher
QFutureWatcher<int> watcher;

// Instantiate an object to receive singal
MyClass myObject;

// Connect slot to watcher's finished() signal
connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(finished()), &myObject, SLOT(handleFinished()));

// Attach watcher to the future
watcher.setFuture(future);

// [B] Will the handleFinished() slot be called at this point even if the concurrent job already completed in point [A] above?
```

And, most importantly, if this does not happen, how can I make the `handleFinished()` slot always be called in this case?

Comment: I wrote a small test program to verify this, and the answer is luckily YES, the signal will be fired in this case. I will add this as an answer if it is useful to you.